# Testing for top 3 options

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, frequency

I have data as shown in the chart below. There are 1144 rows of data and for each data row, an event (A, B, C, ..., I) could either have occurred or not occurred (that is, on or off; binary). For example, A and B could be present in one row and only C in another row. (The events actually represent characteristics that are present or not present in a user's drawing on a picture).

My hypothesis is that A, B, and C are the top 3 events (that is, occur the most often). Can I use Pearson's Chi-squared test to check this? I'm thinking that I cannot because the wiki page for it says, "The events considered must be mutually exclusive and have total probability 1." But in my case, the "events" are not mutually exclusive.

I'm currently using R with my data, but I'm a beginner to using it, so solutions with Excel or something else would also be appreciated.

[image: Chart]

The actual number of observations are as follows:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
467 483 127 30  76  47  34  32  20
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide the actual numbers represented in the bar chart.

Comment: @mef good suggestion, I've added it now.

Comment: Maybe you could base it on some version of multivariate logistic regression, for dependent binomial variables?

Comment: Some possibly relevant links: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/3731-how-to-model-non-mutually-exclusive-categorical-variables       http://www.bbk.ac.uk/ems/research/Seminar_info/PDFs/Gilbert.pdf      http://www.uv.es/~bernardo/MultipleChoice.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that seems natural to me.

## Introduction

Suppose there are $n$ observations of the following form: 
\begin{equation}
y_i = (y_{i1}, \ldots, y_{iJ}),
\end{equation}
where $y_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$. Let
\begin{equation}
Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_J),
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
Y_j = \sum_{i=1}^n y_{ij}.
\end{equation}

### The problem

Consider the collection of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,J\}$, each containing $K < J$ elements. 
Let $(S_1, \ldots, S_L)$ denote the collection of those subsets, where $L = \binom{J}{K}$.
Let $M_\ell$ denote the sum of the elements in $\{Y_j: j\in S_\ell\}$:
\begin{equation}
M_\ell = \sum_{j\in S_\ell} Y_j.
\end{equation}
We wish to compute the probability that $M_\ell$ is the maximum:
\begin{equation}
\text{Pr}[\max(M_1, \ldots, M_L) = M_\ell] \qquad\text{for $\ell = 1, \ldots, L$}.
\end{equation}

## A Bayesian framework

Think of $Y$ as being generated from a multinomial distribution:
\begin{equation}
p(Y|\theta) \propto \prod_{j=1}^J \theta_j^{Y_j},
\end{equation}
where $\theta = (\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_J) \in \Delta^{J-1}$, where $\Delta^{J-1}$ denotes the $J-1$-dimensional simplex. (In other words, $\theta_j \ge 0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^J \theta_j = 1$.) This provides a likelihood for $\theta$. Let the prior distribution for $\theta$ be given by the Dirichlet distribution:
\begin{equation}
p(\theta) = \textsf{Dirichlet}(\theta|\alpha) \propto \prod_{j=1}^J \theta_j^{\alpha_j-1},
\end{equation}
where $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_J)$ and $\alpha_j > 0$. The mean of this distribution is $\alpha/\alpha_0$, where $\alpha_0 = \sum_{j=1}^J \alpha_j$. (The variance is inversely related to $\alpha_0$, which is called the concentration parameter.) Note that if $\alpha_j = 1$ for all $j$, then $p(\theta) \propto 1$, a flat distribution.

The Dirichlet distribution is a conjugate prior for the multinomial likelihood. The posterior distribution for $\theta$ is given by
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|Y) \propto p(Y|\theta)\,p(\theta) \propto \prod_{j=1}^J \theta_j^{(\alpha_j + Y_j) - 1} \propto \textsf{Dirichlet}(\theta|\alpha'),
\end{equation}
where $\alpha' = \alpha + Y$. The posterior mean for $\theta$ is 
\begin{equation}
E[\theta|Y] = \alpha'/\alpha_0',
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_0' = \sum_{j=1}^J (\alpha_j + Y_j)$.

## Solution to the problem

The posterior distribution for $\theta$ summarizes what is known about the categories $(1, \ldots, J)$. With this in mind, switch perspective from the elements of $Y$ to the corresponding elements of $\theta$ and use $p(\theta|Y)$ to solve the problem posed above.

Let $m_\ell$ denote the sum of the elements in $\{\theta_j : \theta_j \in S_\ell\}$: 
\begin{equation}
m_\ell = \sum_{j\in S_\ell} \theta_j.
\end{equation}
The joint posterior distribution for $(m_1, \ldots, m_L)$ can be computed from the posterior distribution for $\theta$. 
The posterior mean is one feature of the distribution,
\begin{equation}
E[m_\ell|Y] = \sum_{j \in S_\ell} E[\theta_j|Y] = \frac{1}{\alpha_0'} \sum_{j\in S_\ell} \alpha_j'.
\end{equation}
We wish to compute the posterior probability that $m_\ell$ is the maximal element:
\begin{equation}
\pi_\ell = \text{Pr}[\max(m_1, \ldots, m_L) = m_\ell\,|\,Y] \qquad\text{for $\ell = 1, \ldots, L$}.
\end{equation}
These probabilities will depend on the variance of $p(\theta|Y)$ as well as its mean.
An analytical solution may be possible, but here I describe a numerical solution that is simple to implement.

Make $R$ draws from $\textsf{Dirichelt}(\theta|\alpha')$ and let $r \in \{1,\ldots, R\}$ index the draws. For each draw compute 
\begin{equation}
z^{(r)} = \arg\!\max_{\ell}\ (m_1^{(r)}, \ldots, m_L^{(r)}).
\end{equation} 
Note $z^{(r)} \in \{1, \ldots, L\}$.
Then 
\begin{equation}
\pi_\ell \approx \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^R [z^{(r)} = \ell],
\end{equation}
where $[\,\cdot\,]$ is the *Iverson bracket* defined as
\begin{equation}
[x] = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{$x$ is true} \\
0 & \text{$x$ is false}
\end{cases} .
\end{equation}
The larger $R$ is, the better the approximation. (One can compute a numerical standard error to assess the accuracy of the approximation.)

### Example

Let $J = 9$ and 
\begin{equation}
Y = (467,\ 483,\ 127,\ 30,\  76,\  47,\  34,\  32,\  20).
\end{equation}
In addition, let $\alpha_j = 1$ for all $j \in \{1, \ldots, 9\}$. (Note $\alpha_0' = 1325$.) The mean of the posterior distribution is 
\begin{equation}
E[\theta|Y] \approx (\text{0.353},\text{ 0.365},\text{ 0.097},\text{
   0.023},\text{ 0.058},\text{ 0.036},\text{
   0.026},\text{ 0.025},\text{ 0.016}).
\end{equation}
Let $K = 3$, in which case $L = 84$. Let $S_1 = \{1,2,3\}$ and $S_3 = \{1,2,5\}$. Then $E[m_1|Y] \approx 0.815$ and $E[m_3|Y] \approx 0.777$.

In $R = 10^6$ draws, only $m_1$ and $m_3$ appeared as the maximum, with $m_3$ appearing 170 times. Therefore $\pi_1 \approx 0.998$, $\pi_3 \approx 0.002$, and $\pi_\ell \approx 0$ for all other $\ell$.

Comment: Thanks @mef! I'm wondering if you could edit your answer to include a p-value. A colleague mentioned that maybe setting S' = S_1 and S'' = S \ S', with the null hypothesis as Pr(S') = Pr(S'') will allow us to get a p-value statistic from this approach. Also, what program did you use to generate these results? I'd like to duplicate what you did...

Comment: @t2k32316 You have a hypothesis. I have shown how to compute the _probability_ that your hypothesis is _true_. In my view, that is much better than a p-value for a statistic associated with a null hypothesis. (What is the null hypothesis? What is the statistic?) A p-value cannot tell you anything about the probability that your hypothesis is true. FYI, I used Mathematica to do the computations. You could use r. (rdirichlet is in the gtools package and combn is in the utils package.)

Comment: that makes sense. I'm still hoping for non-Bayesian answer approach as well, but I really like your answer too. If no one else responds, I'll accept your answer...